# Did Jesus challenge the Principles and Teachings of King Solomon and those of the Prophets before him?

Tags: contradiction, moses, torah, solomon, commandments-of-jesus

During Jesus's epoch,the Jewish Temple in Jerusalem followed mainly the Principles of the Book of Torah(Laws of Moses) and other Prophets that came after him.During that period,Caiaphas,a High Priest in the Jewish Temple,was responsible for the trial and crucifixion of Jesus as he believed that Jesus went against the Laws and teachings of the Temple and Jewish Scholars.

If the Teachings of Moses were also the words of God,and those Principles helped to bring Law and Order in the lives of the common People at that time,then why did Jesus need to go against the Temple and the High Priest?

Comment: There were at least five different or rival interpretations of the Mosaic Law in Christ's time: Pharisees, Sadducees, Essenes (or Zealots), Hellenists, and Samaritans. Each of these believed all the others to more or less go against Moses' teachings.

Comment: Could you cite the passage(s) that you have in mind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is "NO", Jesus was not opposed to the Law - Jesus was opposed to the abuse that the Jewish leaders foisted upon the Jews and the disrespect that abuse engendered.

The law is not abolished (Matt 5:17, 18), “anyone who sets aside one of the least
commandments and teaches others accordingly will be called least in the kingdom of
heaven” (Matt 5:19), “But it is easier for heaven and earth to pass away than for one
dot of the Law to become void.” (Luke 16:17), the law is essential because “through
the law we become conscious of sin” (Rom 3:21, 7:7, 13), “we uphold the law by
faith” (Rom 3:31), “the law is holy, and the commandment is holy, righteous and
good” (Rom 7:12), “the law is spiritual” (Rom 7:14), “the law is good” (1 Tim 1:8),
keeping the law is to do right (James 2:8).

However, Jesus was fiercely opposed to the abuse that the leaders practiced - see the seven curses/woes that Jesus pronounced in Matt 23 - there are few places where Jesus used stronger language than here.